# .How to create fluid layout with css, such that it works on all devices and also on Landscape and Portrait Mode

Tags: html, css

I want to create a fluid layout for mobile devices with the help of CSS..

can u plz suggest some examples ?

I have tried some examples , but I'm fighting to work with orientation change problem.

As I change orientation Firstly it takes time to readjust architecture and Secondly Sometimes Divs(architecture) get distorted a little bit

Comment: Look at Twitter Bootstrap and go from there: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

Comment: Have you tried anything out yet? Done any research? Try looking up on Google the terms "CSS media queries" and "Responsive website design." Always try Google first, this is a place for actual code problems, not resource hunting. Good luck in your search :)

Comment: @Jan and Kyle.. I have already done one architecture page with css
but its not responsive one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you to have fixed and fluid layout:

`Bootstrap`-http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

`Use of Media Queries`-which I prefer most

```
@media screen and (max-device-width : 320px)
{
  body or yourdiv element
  {
    width:<size>px/em/cm;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-device-width : 1204px)
{
  body or yourdiv element
  {
    width:<size>px/em/cm;
  }
}
```

Use template which is specially design for mobile like below one:-

`Mobile Jquery`-use their CSS http://jquerymobile.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try this link http://csslayoutgenerator.com/

You can create `fluid and fixed layout` by using the options in the above link